# Sincronizar funciones que no son promesas javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, asincronismo

No logro hacer que el recorrido de forEach sea síncrono, debido a que necesito unir esas dos tablas agregando una propiedad por cada objeto.
Primero me resuelve todo el código y al final entrega lo que se encuentra dentro del forEach
Necesito que primero me resuelva el forEach y luego continúe con el resto del código.

Aqui les dejo el código para que me ayuden

```
const getCXP = async (req,res) => {
    const cabecerapago = await db.query('SELECT * from cabecerapago;')
    const response = []
    const f = await cabecerapago.forEach(async cabecera => {
        let detalle = await db.query("SELECT * FROM detallepago WHERE idcabecera = $1;",
        [cabecera.idcabecera])
        cabecera.detalle = detalle
        response.push(cabecera)
        console.log(response)
    })
    console.log(response)
    console.log("ya está")
    res.json(response)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` no espera a la resolución de las promesas, puedes ver esto en la misma [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) del método, de donde cito:

> Note: forEach expects a synchronous function.
>
> forEach does not wait for promises. Make sure you are aware of the
> implications while using promises (or async functions) as forEach
> callback.

> Nota: forEach espera recibir una función sincrónica.
>
> forEach no espera por promesas. Asegurate de estar atento a las
> implicaciones al usar promesas (o funciones asincrónicas) como
> una función de retorno.

Puedes recorrer tu array con un `for`:

```js
const getCXP = async(req, res) => {
  const cabecerapago = await db.query('SELECT * from cabecerapago;')
  const response = []
  for (let i = 0; i < cabecerapago.length; i++) {
    let detalle = await db.query("SELECT * FROM detallepago WHERE idcabecera = $1;", [cabecerapago[i].idcabecera])
    cabecerapago[i].detalle = detalle
    response.push(cabecerapago[i])
    console.log(response)

  }
  console.log(response)
  console.log("ya está")
  res.json(response)
}
```

La desventaja de usar este método es que se espera a que se resuelva una promesa para continuar con la otra, lo cuál puede ser lento si el objeto que estás iterando es muy extenso. Para combatir esto puedes pre-generar un array de promesas y utilizar `Promise.all()` para hacer que todas se ejecuten de manera "paralela" (concurrente) y continuar con tu código cuando todas se resuelvan.

Espero que esto te sea de ayuda!  Buena suerte programando.